# ctrl+shift+x terminator alternative in iTerm MAC os?

Tags: macos, iterm2, iterm

In order to make any tab into the fullscreen window, in Terminator, we have an option with shortcut ctrl+shift+X, perhaps I am trying to find the same shortcut in iTerm, but couldn't figure it out. I like to know if there is any shortcut exist or the feature is not present in iTerm.

Comment: Is `command` + `Enter` working for you?

Comment: the following command make the window to occupy full screen not , single tab into full screen

Comment: I am not sure then.

Answer (score 2):

After trial and error, I found it finally

```
cmd+shift+enter
```